# how to move files located in on-premises windows based file share using scala?

Tags: scala, azure-data-factory, fileshare

Background : I am using Azure ADFV2 to move data from fileshare to ADLS, after the file is moved successfully I want to archive the file within fileshare location.

How do I connect to on-premises windows based file share and move the files from one folder to another within the fileshare using scala. I am not sure how to establish the connectivity to a file share.

Comment: Too less of information. Better ask people in your organization about how they do it?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh - added more info

Comment: why do you have to use scala?

Comment: My last activity is spark in ADF, hence thought I can achieve within the scala code. Based on the success of spark activity, I have to achieve the files. If there is any other way in ADF also fine.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look of this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-jar

Answer (score 2):

You can use file system linked service to establish the connectivity to a file share.

1. create a self-hosted integration runtime on ADF and install it on your machine.
2. create a file system linked service, and for "Connect via integration runtime" field, choose the self-hosted ir you created in 1.
3. configure you linked service and dataset as the doc instructs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system

Comment: I don't have a problem with copy files from fileshare, I want to move files within fileshare. There is no move activity in ADF.

Comment: Sorry that I misunderstood. Adf does not support delete now but it's in the roadmap.